# How to copy new files only in a folder to another one in Windows?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am looking for a way to copy new files only from a folder to another one. The criteria are:

- No PowerShell.
- No software, just batch shell.
- Timestamp in milliseconds or seconds, not minutes.
- No sync. Files on folder B can be deleted, I only need new files from folder A to by copied.

Workflow:

- Watch folder A.
- New file written, copy to folder B.

I have tried with `xcopy` and `robocopy` but as far as I understand, using the timestamp in both is in days **while I want to compare the timestamp in milliseconds**.

```
XCOPY
/D:mm-dd-yyyy
         Copy files changed on or after the specified date.
         If no date is given, copy only files whose
         source date/time is newer than the destination time.
```

```
ROBOCOPY
/minage:<n>     Specifies the minimum file age (exclude files newer than n days or date).
```

The ideal solution I have in mind (forgive my ignorance here as I am not a windows user):

```
@REM new_only.bat
CURRENT_TIME=%date%%time%
SOURCE_DIR="c:\source"
TARGET_DIR="c:\target"

:start
xcopy %SOURCE_DIR% %TARGET_DIR% /time>%CURRENT_TIME%
goto start
```

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://serverfault.com/questions/55733/the-job-and-monitoring-options-of-robocopy - check the `/mon` and `/mot` options of robocopy

Comment: Thanks, @SomeWittyUsername but this will not work when I delete files on the target directory. It will see that as a change and re-copy the old files.